# JS Function to Change Some Item in CSS File

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to change some CSS parameters for HTML element based on the `mouseOver` status (true/false)

Ex:

When `mouseOver=true` the text color should be changed to blue

When `mouseOver=false` the text color should use the value in CSS file

The problem here, how I can tell the function to look into the original value in CSS file instead of passing the original value manually through the function?

Below is my code. n=the mouse status. And I am changing the visibility value based on n value.

In the IF statement, how I can tell the function to use the original value that already in CSS file?

```
function showitem(n) {
    if (n==true) {
        document.getElementById('colorstest').style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
    if (n==false) {
        document.getElementById('colorstest').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting it to an empty string will force it to use the value defined in CSS. The reason for this is empty string is an invalid value and the browser will resort to using the next available valid value defined, i.e. from your CSS.

i.e. `document.getElementById('colorstest').style.visibility = '';`

also, you do not need 2 `if` statements there, an `else` would do.

```
if (n==true) {
    document.getElementById('colorstest').style.visibility = '';
}
else {
    document.getElementById('colorstest').style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```